# Install Rglpk on R in Mac

Tags: r, macos

install.packages("Rglpk")
Installing package into '/private/var/folders/wv/ts_skhj91nqg7cdxdggxgj_m0000gn/T/RtmpHpie9Q/downloaded_packages'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: 'Rglpk'
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source package 'Rglpk'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rglpk_0.6-3.tar.gz'

## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 20892 bytes (20 KB)

downloaded 20 KB

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2017c.1.0/zoneinfo/Asia/Hong_Kong'
* installing *source* package 'Rglpk' ...
** package 'Rglpk' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rglpk'
* removing '/private/var/folders/wv/ts_skhj91nqg7cdxdggxgj_m0000gn/T/RtmpHpie9Q/downloaded_packages/Rglpk'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'Rglpk' had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/private/var/folders/wv/ts_skhj91nqg7cdxdggxgj_m0000gn/T/RtmpHpie9Q/downloaded_packages'

**I already tried using homebrew to install glpk. Still, I get this error message.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what Google says about your error - run this into Terminal
`xcode-select --install` and it should install fine.

Comment: Glad to help. This link may be useful to you: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)